# /bin/sh: python: command not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, komodo

I just installed Python3 and Komodo.  I'm trying to run a simple script but am getting the error that the py: command not found.  I'm completly new to both Komodo and Python so don't know where to look.  I saw a another post with the same problem but not a solution that helped.  I have Python3 installed and verified from terminal command.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: instead of `py` use `python` or `python3`

Comment: As far as I know, `py` is just a wrapper for Windows. It's not a standard Python binary name.

Comment: I think this is the answer you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73709162/4592559.

Answer (score 9):

You are trying to run your script using `py` which is not a valid command on your system, hence the error. Try:

```
python3 script.py
```

Comment: The training video I was watching said that py was a special command to run the python interpreter.  Whatever that means.  I replaced py with python3 and it worked fine.  Not sure what the video was trying to do.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Author must be using Windows OS because `py` is just a wrapper around `python` command in Windows systems.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing `py"%F"` with `python3 %F` when you create the run command.