# How to run python3 code in VSCode? /bin/sh: 1: python: not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run a python file in VSCode using python3.

I can run using **integrated terminal** like it says in the [microsoft vscode tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) on python. However, I would like the program to print in the **output tab** and not take up the terminal window. However I'm getting this error.

[image]

The standard *code runner* config file `launch.json`, looks like this;

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
]
```

I've tried to set my python path in VSCode in `settings.json`

```
...
"python.pythonPath": "python3",
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "python3": "/usr/bin/python3"
}
```

I've also set an alias for python -> python3 (as my ubuntu 20.04 doesn't come with python2 anymore)

```
alias python="python3"
```

However, I keep getting the above error. Any Ideas?

Comment: I'm no `bash` geek, but aliases only last in the session (I think).

Comment: If you open a terminl and type `which python` what do you get?

Comment: which python3 returns -> `/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: which python returns -> `python: aliased to python3`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Solution in 2024**

Step1 : Goto settings of Code Runner extension

Step2 : Find the section

> **Code-runner: Executor Map**

And click on

> **Edit in settings.json**

Step3 : Now change the setting for python

Before

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    ...
    "python": "python -u"
    ...
}
```

Change this to

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    ...
    "python": "python3 -u"
    ...
}
```

Comment: It works. However, I have a question. If I simply specify `python3 -u` as the runner, it will use the default interpreter of the OS, I think. This will cause a potential problem, the interpreter of the runner is not the same as the one of the virtual env for the project?

Answer (score 26):

**NOTE: no longer working solution. See solution above**

Nearly had it. This code

```
"python.pythonPath": "python3",
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "python3": "/usr/bin/python3"
}
```

should be

```
"python.pythonPath": "python3",
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "python": "/usr/bin/python3"
}
```

(The difference is at the beginning of line 3)

Comment: FYI - I think this is no longer working with the latest version of vscode: "python.pythonPath" has been deprecated: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/11015

The answer below suggests a way to solve this as of 2023: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73709162/3185183

Answer (score 14):

In the terminal of vscode, type `sudo apt install python-is-python3`. After the installation is done just run the code again and enjoy.

Comment: Is this command for Mac?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution

```
"python.pythonPath": "python3",
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "python": "$pythonPath -u $fullFileName"
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Those coming later, if you have Code Runner installed, then you have to go into the settings by going into code-runner: Executor Map "Edit in settings.json" and locate the python section

```
{
"workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
"code-runner.executorMap": {

    "javascript": "node",
    "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
    "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "objective-c": "cd $dir && gcc -framework Cocoa $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "php": "php",
    "python": "python -u",
    "perl": "perl",
    "perl6": "perl6",
    "ruby": "ruby",
    "go": "go run",
    "lua": "lua",
    "groovy": "groovy",
    "powershell": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File",
    "bat": "cmd /c",
    "shellscript": "bash",
    "fsharp": "fsi",
    "csharp": "scriptcs",
    "vbscript": "cscript //Nologo",
    "typescript": "ts-node",
    "coffeescript": "coffee",
    "scala": "scala",
    "swift": "swift",
    "julia": "julia",
    "crystal": "crystal",
    "ocaml": "ocaml",
    "r": "Rscript",
    "applescript": "osascript",
    "clojure": "lein exec",
    "haxe": "haxe --cwd $dirWithoutTrailingSlash --run $fileNameWithoutExt",
    "rust": "cd $dir && rustc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "racket": "racket",
    "scheme": "csi -script",
    "ahk": "autohotkey",
    "autoit": "autoit3",
    "dart": "dart",
    "pascal": "cd $dir && fpc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "d": "cd $dir && dmd $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "haskell": "runhaskell",
    "nim": "nim compile --verbosity:0 --hints:off --run",
    "lisp": "sbcl --script",
    "kit": "kitc --run",
    "v": "v run",
    "sass": "sass --style expanded",
    "scss": "scss --style expanded",
    "less": "cd $dir && lessc $fileName $fileNameWithoutExt.css",
    "FortranFreeForm": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "fortran-modern": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "fortran_fixed-form": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "fortran": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
}
```

}

change this

```
"python": "python -u",
```

or something similar so that it looks like this

```
"python": "python3",
```

this is because this is new command to run python code in Python 3

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `python3` path in linux by pasting this line before your code in visual studio:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt install python-is-python3
```

type the above command line and it will work.

Comment: This solution was already provided by someone. Duplicate answers are not helpful.