# VS Code Setup, cannot find python 3

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I have been trying to make vscode work for centuries now it seems, but i cant seem to make it work. I installed python extenion on vscode.

This is settings.json

```
{
"python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3",
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
"python.linting.enabled": true,
"workbench.settings.editor": "json",
"workbench.settings.useSplitJSON": true
}
```

This is my python path

```
python3: /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3.8-config /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/python3.8 /usr/lib/python3 /etc/python3.8 /etc/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.8 /usr/include/python3.8 /usr/share/python3 /usr/share/man/man1/python3.1.gz
```

This the error for helloworld program

```
[Running] python -u "/home/hbahsir/Documents/Python Scripts/hello.py"
/bin/sh: 1: python: not found

[Done] exited with code=127 in 0.009 seconds
```

I want to make vscode work but I cant.

EDIT: I am using a linux system

Comment: you tried `python3 -u "/home/hbahsir/Documents/Python Scripts/hello.py"`?

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 I didnt try it it was run by default like this by vscode

Comment: can you try that cmd in your terminal/cmd-line and see if that works?

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 yes it works in terminal... but it is not working in VScode

Comment: Yes it solved it, thankyou!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run python3 code in VSCode? /bin/sh: 1: python: not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61620036/how-to-run-python3-code-in-vscode-bin-sh-1-python-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

The error simply means that `python` is not present in your environment variables. Your `python3` does point to a `PYTHONPATH` which is why it worked in your terminal. So what you can simply do - [make 'python' program command execute Python 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3)

**If not then try the following**

It seems like `python` which is used by `vscode` as default doesnt resolve to any interpreter. You can try changing by doing the following:

You can select your interpreter from `command palette`. The following instructions are from [DonJayamanne's Github](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/wiki/Miscellaneous#select-an-interpreter).

> Select the command `Python: Select Workspace Interpreter` from the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_command-palette)
>
> Upon selecting the above command a list of discovered interpreters will be displayed in a quick pick list

Select an interpreter from this that is different from what is currently active and see if that solves it.

[image: Command Pallet Screenshot]

Comment: man I tried doing it as well, but still it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me..

option 1(easy way):
install `python-is-python3` package

(install command) `sudo apt-get install python-is-python3`

option 2(faster way):
make aliases,

1. run `gedit ~./bashrc` in terminal
2. go to the end of the file and add these 2 lines

`alias python=python3`

`alias pip=pip3`

Then save and close file and restart terminal