# Error while Python "Run Code" option in VSCode environment in LInux

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Triggering **/bin/sh: 1: python: not found** error while running .py in VSCODE environment. Can anyone guide me through the necessary steps to correct it?
P.S: New in VSCode environment for LINUX.[Screenshot_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvjdM.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run python3 code in VSCode? /bin/sh: 1: python: not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61620036/how-to-run-python3-code-in-vscode-bin-sh-1-python-not-found)

Comment: Is python on you path outside. Start a shell and type python. What result do you get. Then do the same inside vs code. open a terminal and type python. does it work?

Comment: Have you followed the steps in the VSCode tutorial? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python

Comment: Both version is coming same... (3.8.5)

Comment: @RandomDavis I went through that thread, opened the required JSON, but could not find the place where I need to change the code. :(. Can you let me know the place where I need to change it? Thanks.

Comment: so it does not work outside vs code?  That is your problem!

Comment: @NicolasMartinez went through the link, Now its working fine, the Issue was with PIP installer. Thanks.

Comment: @PaulBrennan its now working. Thanks.

Comment: quit a username to type each time you login, if you don't explain in detail what the solution is we will get this question each week, we are here to help you and you are to help others

Answer (score 0):

To get started in working with Python with Visual Studio Code, I would recommend that you follow [the official guide in the VSCode documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python)