# Enter an integer and find all palindromes lesser than or equal to the given number

Tags: python

I do not understand why my code is not working, could anyone help me with this one? It is supposed to print a list of palindromes (numbers that are equal to themselves if read backwards) lesser than or equal to the input. When I try to execute it, it writes: /bin/sh: python: command not found.

```
w = input('Enter a number: ')
n = int(w)
g = []
for n in range(n, 0, -1):
    r = 0
    while n != 0:
        a = n % 10
        r = r * 10 + a
        n //= 10
    if n == r:
        g.append()
print(g)
```

Comment: What command do you use to execute it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53233973/bin-sh-python-command-not-found should answer this...

Comment: Look at your `while` loop.  The loop condition is `n != 0`.  That means that `n` must be `0` when the loop exits.  Now look at the `if` after the loop.  It's checking to see if `n == r`, which is equivalent to `r == 0` (since `n` is `0`).  Do you see why this doesn't work?

Comment: What command do you use to execute it?: I just click on the Run Code button in Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. Actually your `if n == r:` is always computing like `if 0 == r:`. Hence, in your `for` loop assign your `n` to a `temp` variable. Try this:

```
w = input('Enter a number: ')
n = int(w)
g = []
for n in range(n, 0, -1):
    temp = n
    r = 0
    while n != 0:
        a = n % 10
        r = r * 10 + a
        n //= 10
    
    if temp == r:
        g.append(temp)
print(g)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution, which is simpler than using a while loop:

```
n = int(input("Enter a number:\n"))

g = []
for i in range(0, n+1):
    if str(i)==str(i)[::-1]:
        g.append(i)
print(g)
```

Comment: OP wants every palindrome less than or equal to n not less than or equal to  n-1

Comment: @nin17 You're right; I have solved it.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think your code works anyway. Here is another way to find palindromes less than w:

```
w = input('Enter a number: ')
n = int(w)
palindromes = []
for i in range(n+1):
    if str(i) == str(i)[::-1]:
        palindromes.append(i)
print(palindromes)
```